# Spring MVC Passing object from a foreach to another Controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I've a list of object which is dispayed by a `forEach` spring tag. Here's the code of the jsp :

```
<c:forEach items="${liste_fiche}" var="fiche">
                <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <form:form action="display_fiche" method="post" commandName="fiche" varStatus="status">
                        <div class="card-content white-text">
                            <span class="card-title">Fiche numéro ${fiche.id}</span>
                        <p>reference de la fiche : ${fiche.ref_fiche}</p>
                        <p>type de fiche : ${fiche.typeFiche}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">

                            <button type="submit" action="display_fiche"
                                class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Afficher la fiche</button>

                        </div>
                    </form:form>
                </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

The code above has the following reuslt : 
[image: displaying of fiches]

When I click on "Afficher la fiche" I would like to go on another controller with the actual fiche object selected.

I tried to do it by the following controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="display_fiche", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private ModelAndView displayFiche(@ModelAttribute("fiche") Fiche fiche, ModelMap modelMap) {
    System.out.println("Fiche séléctionnée : " + fiche.getId());
    return model;
}
```

I don't know if it's the good way to do, because it does not work. I always get a '0' to `fiche.getId()`. If it's not possible, how can I just pass only the `fiche.id` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" action="display_fiche" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
Afficher la fiche
</button>
```

Create a hidden input to keep clicked id.

In the button above add a JavaScipt call to store the clicked id into the hidden input before actual submitting the form.

But it seems you dont' need such a complicated way with `form` and `post`. It is enough to use usual `<a>` tag and have get mapping on the controller side. Moreover it's enough to pass just fiche id.

```
<a href="/display_fiche/${fiche.id}" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
Afficher la fiche
</a>
```

and controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/display_fiche/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private ModelAndView displayFiche(@PathVariable("id") Long id, ModelMap modelMap) {
    System.out.println("Fiche séléctionnée : " + id);
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I will use your second solution. Indeed, the GET request with a `href` seems to be good for me :)